# How to get current date with reset time 00:00 in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, date, datetime, time

Hey I am using calendar instance to get current date and time.

```
private fun getCurrentCalendar() { Calendar.getInstance() }
```

Output:- `Wed Jul 20 21:45:52 GMT+01:00 2022`

If I want to reset time I need to use this function

```
fun resetCalendarTime(calendar: Calendar) {
     calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
     calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
     calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
     calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
}
```

it will give this

```
Wed Jul 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2022
```

My question is there any efficient way of doing that or this is fine in android?

Comment: Maybe not helpful in the immediate moment, but this sounds to me like a reason to use `java.time` or one of the JSR-310 backport libraries, so that you have access to classes like `LocalDate` instead of having to deal with java.util.Calendar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caveat: Java syntax shown here, as I have not yet learned Kotlin.

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now( zoneId ).atStartOfDay( zoneId )
```

## Details

The terrible `java.util.Calendar` class was years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Never use either `Date` class, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, or any other legacy date-time class found outside the `java.time` package.

## On JVM

If you are running Kotlin on a [JVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine), use *java.time* classes.

To get the current moment as seen in a particular time zone, use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
```

If you want to use the JVM’s current default time zone:

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.systemDefault() ;
```

Apparently you want the first moment of the day. Your Question makes the mistake of assuming that time is always 00:00. Actually, on some dates in some time zones, the first moment occurs at a different time such as 01:00.

So let *java.time* determine the first moment of the day. Call [`LocalDate#atStartOfDay`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html#atStartOfDay()).

A `LocalDate` represents a date-only value, without time-of-day, and without time zone or offset. Calling `atStartOfDay` returns a `ZonedDateTime`, like that seen above.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z ) ;
ZonedDateTime startOfToday = today.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

Here is an example of a day starting at 1 AM.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Amman" ) ;
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2021 , 3 , 26 ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;
```

See this [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/c9Zt00). Notice the time is 01:00.

> 2021-03-26T01:00+03:00[Asia/Amman]

To generate text in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format wisely extended to append the name of the time zone in square brackets, merely call `ZonedDateTime#toString`. See example result quoted directly above this paragraph.

To generate text in other formats, use `DateTimeFormatter`, and optionally `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`. To automatically localize, use `DateTimeFormatter#ofLocalizedDateTime`.

All of this has been covered many many times on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more.

## Off JVM

I recall that some part of the Kotlin community was working on a Kotlin-based port of a subset of *java.time* functionality to be used for Kotlin-based apps not running on a JVM.

I imagine that ported library works similar to code shown above.