# Find all nearest date from list of date in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have current date and I have of list which is coming from server. I want to find all first nearest data.

```
"Results": [
        {
            "date": "May 9, 2020 8:09:03 PM",
            "id": 1
        },
        {
            "date": "Apr 14, 2020 8:09:03 PM",
            "id": 2
        },
        {
            "date": "Mar 15, 2020 8:09:03 PM",
            "id": 3
        },
        {
            "date": "May 9, 2020 8:19:03 PM",
            "id": 4
        }
    ],
```

Today date is `Wed Jul 20 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2022` I am getting through this my own [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73057988/11560810). Inside this SO I am taking current date.

**Expected Output**

```
[Result(date=May 9, 2020 8:09:03 PM, id = 1), Result(date=May 9, 2020 8:19:03 PM, id = 4)]
```

So How can I do in idiomatic way in kotlin ?

Comment: **1.** Convert each of those date strings to Dates and reset the time to 00:00 as done your other question. Hint: use `map`. **2.** Then use `minBy` to get the smallest date difference in days. That will give just one result. **3.** If you want both results, then use `groupBy` the date diff and then take the smallest value. **4.** Provide a [**minimal reproducible example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then ask a _specific question_ about your algorithm or technique.  "Implement this feature for me" is off-topic for this site.

Comment: What does "all first" mean? Doesn't "all" contradict "first"? Do you mean to search for N nearest dates?

Comment: Yes all N nearest date

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few ways this question could be solved with, ranging from simple to moderately complex depending on requirements such as efficiency. With some assumptions, below is a linear-time solution that is decently idiomatic and is only 3 lines in essence.

```kotlin
import kotlin.math.abs
import java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit
import java.time.temporal.Temporal

data class Result(val date: LocalDateTime, val id: Int)

fun getClosestDays(toDate: Temporal, results: List<Result>): List<Result> {
    // Find the minimum amount of days to the current date
    var minimumDayCount = MAX_VALUE
    results.forEach { minimumDayCount = minOf(minimumDayCount, abs(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(toDate, it.date))) }
    
    // Grab all results that match the minimum day count
    return results.filter { abs(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(toDate, it.date)) == minimumDayCount }
}

fun main() {
    getClosestDays(
        LocalDateTime.now(), 
        listOf(
            Result(LocalDateTime.of(2020, 5, 9, 8, 9, 3), 1),
            Result(LocalDateTime.of(2020, 4, 14, 8, 9, 3), 2),
            Result(LocalDateTime.of(2020, 3, 15, 8, 9, 3), 3),
            Result(LocalDateTime.of(2020, 5, 9, 8, 19, 3), 4)
        )
    ).also { println(it) }
}
```

Here is the output:

```
[Result(date=2020-05-09T08:09:03, id=1), Result(date=2020-05-09T08:19:03, id=4)]
```

And [here](https://pl.kotl.in/EpQ6mQoGt) you can play with it yourself.

Comment: Hey @Ved what is `Temporal` ?

Comment: It is basically some type representing time. You could just as well make it something like `LocalDateTime` if that's the only thing you'd need it to be. You can find all implementing classes on its [doc page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html).